# Is there a verb that means "make lukewarm"?

Tags: word-request

Is there a verb that means "make lukewarm"? I am trying to use it to say that the relations between two people instead of warming up as become lukewarm, but I don't know any verb that means "make lukewarm" or "become lukewarm".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say their relationship "cooled," that doesn't necessarily mark lukewarm as an endpoint though. You could also use "drift apart" if your idiom doesn't have to include temperature